# How to create a dynamic proxy with polymorphic delegation?

Tags: java, proxy-classes

I want to create a dynamic proxy, which can delegate its methods to different implementations (each method invocation chooses a potentially different object). And I want to achieve the polymorphic effect, like when some proxied method calls another proxied method, the object selection mechanism does apply again.

Okay, enough confusion, here is an example:

```
interface IService {
  void a();
  void b();
}

class HappyService implements IService {
  public void a() {
    System.out.println("Happy a");
    b();
  }

  public void b() {
    System.out.println("Happy b");
  }
}

class SadService implements IService {
  public void a() {
    System.out.println("Sad a");
    b();
  }

  public void b() {
    System.out.println("Sad b");
  }
}
```

Now, I want to create a proxy for `IService` which always chooses `HappyService` for invocations of method `a()` and `SadService` for invocations of method `b()`. Here is what comes to my mind at first:

```
InvocationHandler h = new InvocationHandler() {
  @Override
  public Object invoke( final Object proxy, final Method method, final Object[] args ) throws Throwable {
    Object impl;
    if (method.getName().equals("a")) {
      impl = new HappyService();
    } else if (method.getName().equals("b")) {
      impl = new SadService();
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported method: " + method.getName());
    }
    return method.invoke(impl, args);
  }
};
IService service = (IService)Proxy.newProxyInstance( IService.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{ IService.class }, h );
service.a();
```

This prints:

```
Happy a
Happy b
```

Yeah, that's because the invocation of `b()` inside of `a()` does not know anything about the dynamic proxy.

So, how do I best achieve my goal? My desired output is:

```
Happy a
Sad b
```

I could probably replace my `new HappyService()` inside the invocation handler with yet another proxy, which passes only method `a()` to `HappyService`, and redirects all other methods back to the original proxy. But maybe there is a better/easier solution?

Comment: Eh, I've tried the idea from the last paragraph and now I see that I can't do it. So, I'm completely stuck.

Comment: I hit the same problem and used [javassist](http://www.javassist.org) to create a proxy rather than using `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`.  Take a look at https://github.com/hertzsprung/autumn/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/datumedge/autumn/Singletoniser.java for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proxy can only be used to intercept inter-object calls, when the caller has a reference to the proxy instead of the "real" implementation. Here, both your implementations of `a()` call `b()` directly, so of course they call it on `this`. What you want to do cannot be achieved by proxies.

However, you can do it using AOP, for example using [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php) and either [compile-time weaving](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ajc-ref.html) (also available with the aspectj-maven-plugin) or [load-time weaving](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html). Roughly, you create an [aspect](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html) with pointcuts on the [calling sites](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html#call-vs-execution) of the `a()` and `b()` methods in the `IService` implementations, and you advise the execution, which might be to replace the original call by another. Untested code, but it looks like this:

```
public aspect IServiceAspect {
    private IService happy = new HappyService(); // Assuming these are stateless services
    private IService sad = new SadService();     // that can be shared.

    // The pointcut is inside an IService implementation, and is a call to the a() method
    pointcut aCall(): within(IService+) && call(* IService.a());

    pointcut bCall(): within(IService+) && call(* IService.b());

    around(): aCall() && !within(HappyService) { // To avoid infinite recursion
        return happy.a();
    }

    around(): bCall() && !within(SadService) {
        return sad.b();
    }
}
```

You can then provide directly an `HappyService` or `SadService` implementation as an `IService`, both have been modified. You can also create a single pointcut matching all the methods of `IService`, and do the routing dynamically based on the method name (using `thisJoinPoint` in the advice), like in your example.

Aspects can also be declared using [annotations](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Frank! I'm afraid I can't introduce AspectJ in the project. Do you know of any aspect tools capable of solving this problem, but which don't introduce new syntax beyond Java?

Comment: There's an AspectJ syntax using annotations, but they themselves contain bits of AspectJ syntax, obviousky. However, I don't see how that can be avoided (using AspectJ or equivalent), short of doing the job yourself using asm or javassist, which would be a lot more error-prone.